# How do I play a specific genre 'radio' on Spotify?

Tags: spotify

When I search for 'downtempo', it only shows albums, artists, and songs with the word 'downtempo'. How do I play music of the whole genre downtempo? The closest thing they have is playlists with the word 'downtempo' in it, but that is a fixed length playlist made by another user, and those playlists won't play on mobile. It just says "Cannot play station. Sorry this station cannot be started. Please try another one."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spotify Moderators](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Newcomers-and-Contribution/Search-Radio-based-on-Genre/td-p/102827), they removed the genre radio feature back in 2012.

I think the closest think you can do based on what you're asking is to search for your genre (i.e. Downtempo), find a playlist that has some songs you already know, and start a radio station based off of that playlist. You can also browse genre play lists by going to the "Browse" section.

Comment: You can't play a radio station based off a playlist. It says "Cannot play station. Sorry this station cannot be started. Please try another one."

Comment: I discovered you can use `genre:downtempo` and Enter to list thousands of songs in that genre, then play the songs with shuffle.

Comment: Are you using the Web Player or the Desktop App? Either way it lets me create a radio station based on a playlist. I'm not sure if this feature is changed based on your country though.

Comment: Desktop App. Strange it's doing it now. I was going to capture a screen shot, and then it worked. I kind of like the `genre:downtempo` feature though. Lots of songs I've never heard!

Comment: Glad you found something that works!

Comment: Spotify just removed playlist radio right clicks. A workaround is here: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/What-happened-to-quot-Playlist-Radio-quot/m-p/4636188/highlight/true#M69043